# How to make Snap.svg responsive in ie?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, snap.svg

this.svgCanvas = Snap("#svg");

this.svgCanvas.attr({ viewBox: "0 0 236 236"});

For all other browsers it will be responsive after setting the view box.
 I am using IE11 , it will not be responsive. the height is always fixed to 
 some small value. So sometimes the svg image will be clipped.

[See example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNKmM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to make your svg responsive in all browser.

- calculate the total width of your svg image.
- set view box width and height same, ie, the calculated width earlier(you can change as well as whatever the aspect ratio you needed).
- this.svgCanvas.attr({ viewBox: "0 0 236 236", height: innerWidth });

here 236 is my calculated width of svg image.